# Unix C#: SocketException Unknown Error -1

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, icmp

I am very new to using to using C# but have had experience using Java and C++. I am need to make a Traceroute program for school and cannot seem to have the program ping properly. I am on MacOs and Mono 5.10.1.57.

At first, I tried using the Ping class and PingOptions like the example provided on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingoptions(v=vs.110).aspx. I set the Ttl to 1 and the program ignored the ttl settings that I made. I found that others have had this same issue: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9350.

After, I decided to try to do it using a raw socket type and now am receiving the error: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: "Unknown error: -1".

Here is my code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Icmp);
socket.Ttl = 1;
socket.SendTo(packet_buffer, 54, 0, endPointServer);
```

Thank You!

Edited:
My exception occurs on line 1 when the Socket is instantiated.

Comment: On many systems, using raw sockets is [a privileged operation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312857/how-does-macos-allow-standard-users-to-ping). `SocketType.Dgram` may just work, despite the docs advertising `Raw`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I got this solution to work. If you submit this as an answer I will mark it as correct.